# Best way to move an element around (performance wise)

Tags: javascript, performance, css, transform

I need to move a DOM element horizontally. The dragging begins on **mousedown**, moves on **mousemove** and ends on **mouseup**

All this needs to happen on a site with tons of animations and stuff on it, so performance is crucial. With what I have now I do see some delay; the element moves a little bit behind the mouse movement. It just looks ugly this way.

So, basically I have something like the following:

```
var offset = 0, startX;
$('.draggable').on('mousedown', function (e) {
        startX = e.pageX;
    })
    .on('mouseup', function() {
        startX = null;
    })
    .on('mousemove', function (e) {
        if(startX) {
           newX = e.pageX;
           offset += newX - startX;
           startX = newX;
           this.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'translate(' + offset + 'px)';
        }
    });
```

([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CxTY6/))

I was wondering what changes to this code could improve performance ?

UPDATE: For example, what about requestAnimationFrame and FPS, can it help ?

Comment: I would start by dropping jquery.

Comment: true, although I doubt that in this case where I only use it to bind event it doesn't matter much

Comment: I doubt your doubt is correct. Especially since you are concerned about performance. Even 2.0 normalizes stuff you probably don't need. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/2.1.0-rc1/src/event.js

Comment: And considering you are asking for the most performant way and you only target webkit, including jquery for what you want to do is "pretty stupid" imho.

Answer (score 1):

Not a huge improvement, but you can write:

```
var offset = 0, startX;
$('.draggable').on('mousedown', function (e) {
        startX = e.pageX - offset;
    })
    .on('mouseup', function() {
        startX = null;
    })
    .on('mousemove', function (e) {
        if(startX) {
           offset = e.pageX - startX;
           this.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'translate(' + offset + 'px)';
        }
    });
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CxTY6/1/)

Comment: Thnx for the improvement, its at least a step forward!